# How to replace data inside a sqlite database if it already exist python?

Tags: python, sqlite

**I am trying to add replace data in a database but it always create a new data instead of replacing the already existing data.what shall i do?**

```
# Import module
import sqlite3
#data 
name = "ravi"
std = "12"
sec = "b"

conn = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Creating table
table ="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STUDENT(NAME VARCHAR(255), CLASS VARCHAR(255),
SECTION VARCHAR(255));"""
cursor.execute(table)

# Queries to INSERT records.
cursor.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO STUDENT VALUES (?,?,?)''',(name,std,sec))
cursor.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO STUDENT VALUES ('Shyam', '8th', 'B')''')
cursor.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO STUDENT VALUES ('Baburao', '9th', 'C')''')

# Display data inserted
print("Data Inserted in the table: ")
data=cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM STUDENT''')
for row in data:
    print(row)

# Commit your changes in the database   
conn.commit()

# Closing the connection
conn.close()
```

Comment: The table needs a unique key so it can tell that this is a duplicate that needs to be replaced.

Comment: use the SQL `UPDATE` command

Answer (score 0):

After creating table, you need to create unique index with 3 fields `name` `class` `section`

If you have already duplicated fields in your database, remove the duplicated rows first.

```
unique_index_query = """CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_name_class_section ON STUDENT(NAME, CLASS, SECTION);"""
cursor.execute(unique_index_query)
```

You can reference more here

[Sqlite3 Create Index](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/)